# Symfony2 - Form method switching from POST to GET?

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm building a login form manually in Symfony2 (not using the form builder) and for some reason the POST method is ignored; the target page sees a GET request, so I have no access to the posted field values.

Here's the form:

```
<form action="/mysite/web/dologin" method="POST">
   Email: <input name=email type=text size=40>
   Password: <input name=password type=password size=40>
   <input type=submit>
</form>
```

And the routing.yml entry:

```
dologin: 
    pattern:  /dologin/
    defaults: { _controller: SiteDefaultBundle:Default:dologin }
```

And the controller action:

```
public function dologinAction()
{
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        var_dump($request);
}
```

I submit the form with values in both fields, but no values come through.  The relevant section of the resulting request dump looks like this; note no fields in "request":

```
  ["request"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#8 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["query"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#9 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ...
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
```

If I change the method to "GET" in the HTML form, the request_method recognized is still GET, but the form values are now available:

```
  ["request"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#8 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["query"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#9 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(13) "test@test.com"
      ["password"]=>
      string(4) "mypw"
    }
  }
```

Why would this be?  Why is POST ignored? Is there an encoding type I need to specify?  I know you can protect forms in Symfony from cross-site attacks; I'm wondering if that's a default configuration value I need to change.

Comment: Did you check that there's no redirect in the process ?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:  I needed to have the form action ('/dologin') and the route specification ('/dologin/') correspond regarding the trailing slash.  Adding a trailing slash to the form action fixed things.